# unauthorized_Client while refreshing google access token

Tags: curl, google-fusion-tables, access-token

I want to upload a csv file to fusion table using curl. I created client id and secret using developer console. Then I generated access token using google playground link.

using the generated access token, I could successfully import data in fusion table from csv file.

Now, the problem is that the access token expired after some time and I have to get new access token using refresh token. This I want to do also using curl, but I get 'unauthorized_client' error while refreshing the access token.

following are the commands used by me.

to upload data in fusion table

curl -s -S --data-binary "INPUT_CSV_FILE" -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_PLAYGROUNDLINK " -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/FUSION_TABLE_ID/import"

Refresh token

curl  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token -d "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN(from playground)&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET"  -X POST

Comment: based on the "unauthorized client" message, I would try adding `-A "Mozilla" ` into your cmd-line, before the `-d ..` Good luck.

Comment: Thankfully, I have reached the solution for problem. I was generating Authentication code in Google playground, but it was not using the client Id  that i generated. Then I generated authentification code with my own http request as follows 
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&
response_type=code&
client_id=CLIENT_ID&
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffusiontables&
approval_prompt=force&
access_type=offline
and used authentication code to generate access token & it worked. Hope this helps someone else too. Thanks #shellter for your help!

Comment: post your solution as an answer below. Then  you can accept your own answer after 48 hrs (or something like that) and gain reputation points. Use the `{}` tool at top left of edit box after selecting text to give it the correct "code" format. Glad you found a solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated authentification code with my own http request as follows **accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth? redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL& response_type=code& client_id=CLIENT_ID& scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffusiontables& approval_prompt=force& access_type=offline** and used authentication code to generate access token & it worked.